# How to download a image in magento admin panel from ordered items

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I have been trying to give a link to admin panel for downloading the product image ordered in `sales > order > view`. Now its done and I have given the link to download as

```
www.example.com/namespace/index(mycontroller)/download(myaction)/name/screen.jpg
```

Inside my controller's action I get the file name as parameter, and I knew the location where the file has been located. Now what should I need to make the image downloadable?

This is my controller action code:

```php
public function downloadAction() {
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
    $file = Mage::getBaseDir(). DS . 'media' . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'upload' . DS . $name;
    $content = readfile($file);
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($name, $content);
}
```

When I try to run the above code I get the following error.

> Cannot send headers; headers already sent

Please help

Comment: This generally means something is already outputted to the screen. You can use the PHP headers_sent function to check which headers have been outputted. Especially look for the content type (text/html) http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Maybe this will give you some extra info that you can append to your question

Comment: Have you tried to open this in a popup ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function downloadAction() {
$name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
$file = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog' . DS . 'upload' . DS . $name;
$content = file_get_contents($file); 
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($name, $content);
}
```

I think so Form above code there is only problem with the path by using these `path("Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog' . DS . 'upload' . DS . $name")` you can download the image

Answer (score 0):

PHP send headers as early as some output appears, this happens here:  `readfile($file)`

From the php.net doc:

> `int readfile ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )`
>
> Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

So, this is the problem. The solution was posted by @Diwakar